# How do I update existing nested value in mongodb at specified position

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to update existing value with add 0 after 3 digit. But have not found a concrete solution in mongoDB. Could anyone please help here.

**Ex :**

```
My Value =12345
Required Value=123045
```

Please provide update statement in MongoDB for Above requirement.

Comment: What is MongoDB version ?

Comment: MongoDB Version 3.4.4

Comment: With `V 3.4.4` - I would suggest to do it code & update DB. That version is from `2016` & as a tip I would suggest to upgrade asap, Also if you're using mongoDB Atlas then you've to upgrade by end of this month, I've seen an email saying they're moving out of `3.4`

Comment: I have done some below code but not able to go ahead.

Comment: "accountDetails" : [ 
        {
            "accountNumber" : "23682880",
            "accountType" : "CC"
  }

Comment: Ok, Can you give us full document & query what you've tried & required o/p

Comment: above is my document and below as my update query

Comment: db.account.updateMany({"accountDetails.accountType":"CC"},
 {$set :{"accountDetails.$.accountNumber" : "need help here "}})

Comment: system team are working on version upgrade process but now we need solution to upgrade existing data. do you need any further details

Comment: Full Documents. {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1feddaf4403f6dcce48ece"),
    "psuId" : "99999999",
    "accountDetails" : [ 
        {
            "accountNumber" : "12345",
            "accountType" : "CC"
        }, 
        {
            "accountNumber" : "25369621",
            "accountType" : "CC"
        }
    ],
    "startDate" : "2018-08-01T11:13:57+00:00",
    "endDate" : "2019-03-08T05:55:00+00:00"
}

Comment: So my question is do you want an update query to dynamically update `12345` to `123045` & `25369621` to `253069621`, Also is this one time operation or will this query exists in code for ever ?

Comment: yes Shrinivasy. I need dynamic update query for accountType="CC" is found we need to update its account by adding 12345 to 123045... Its one time operation

Comment: As far as I know & also as I said, this might not be possible, With `$` you can update an element's `accountNumber ` in an array if that element has `accountType="CC"`, but you need to pass value of `accountNumber` in query, but query can't dynamically pull existing value & add `0` & re-write it back..

Comment: is there any alternate way like by doing any programming in mongoDB to this. I am newer for this technology and suddenly I have facing this type of requirement. can you please help here.

Comment: There `$where` which can run a javascript function & I wouldn't suggest that cause it's not a performant query - also not sure how far it would help you, Hope someone can help you with better any solution, Meanwhile try to read data from DB & manipulate in code & update back :-)